# The Julia @sprintf macro seems to work differently for "e", "f", and "d" format arguments

Tags: julia

I am using Julia 1.0.2.  The Julia `@sprintf` macro seems to produce errors with the "e" format type, when the "f" and "d" format types work Okay for the same numbers.  See examples below:

```
julia> VERSION
v"1.0.2"

julia> using Printf
# Note that this number works fine with "e" format.
julia> @sprintf "%0.4e" 323232329999999329999999
"3.2323e+23"

# Adding the digit 1 to end of above number causes error with "e" format.
julia> @sprintf "%0.4e" 3232323299999993299999991
ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 20-element Array{UInt64,1} at index [21]

# The same number works with the "d" format.
julia> @sprintf "%0.4d" 3232323299999993299999991
"3232323299999993299999991"

# In addition, the same number works with the "f" format.
julia> @sprintf "%0.4f" 3232323299999993299999991
"3232323299999993299999991.0000"

# EDIT: I found a workaround that solves this case, use float():
# Here is the same error as above:
julia> @sprintf "%0.4e" 3232323299999993299999991
ERROR: BoundsError: attempt to access 20-element Array{UInt64,1} at index [21]

# Here is the workaround using the float() function:
julia> @sprintf "%0.4e" float(3232323299999993299999991)
"3.2323e+24"
```

I found similar behavior with the `@printf` macro.

Is there some upper limit to using the `@sprintf` macro for the "e" format that I am unaware of--and that does not apply to the "f" or "d" format types?